# Is there a way to have a material transition between 2 fragments without manually connecting each subview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to get a material transition to work from Fragment1 to Fragment2 in my app.

I've [followed this article](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb) and got it working with a TextView and an ImageView that already exists in each fragment layout.xml using code like this:

```
//set unique transition name    
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.image, "myImageView");

//set the transition name for the ImageView in the fragment layout.xml
android:transitionName="transitionImage"

//then do this when I load the new fragment
ft.addSharedElement(holder.image, "transitionImage");
```

My question is, what if I want to a similar transition between fragments with a LinerLayout or ConstraintLayout that has a lot of child views?  Do I really have to do the above steps for every single TextView or ImageView in that layout?  Is there an easier way?  Thanks.

Comment: There is a great [blog post on transitions](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) - maybe it's helpful on its own (see enter and exit transitions), but if it isn't, please explain what you mean by "material transition"? Something other than Fade or Slide or a combination of both?

Comment: Looks like what I'm trying to do is a "Shared Element Transition".  Actually in that blog post it illustrates the problem I'm having.   [In this video](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/assets/videos/posts/2015/01/12/music-opt.mp4) notice how the image transitions properly but the artist name and title does not.  How would one be able to create a transition where all elements that are similar transition nicely and don't just disappear/reappear?

Comment: Interesting question :) Could you share the two Fragment layouts with the "hero ViewGroups" (the ones with the similar elements)?